# How to Add Prefix to all macros in config.h by Autotool

Tags: config, autotools

How can I add a prefix to all macros defined in `config.h` by Autotool? For example, I want `#define MYNAMESPACE_HAVE_STRING_H 1` instead of `#define HAVE_STRING_H 1`. I have found a post saying that `AX_PREFIX_CONFIG_H` can help but my system doesn't support this macro...

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([include/config.h])
```

Comment: Are you intending to install your `config.h` as a system header?
Otherwise why do want to do this? And in what sense does your system
not support `AX_PREFIX_CONFIG_H`?

Answer (score 2):

`AX_*` macros come from Autoconf Archive, in particular the one you're referring to is described in http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_prefix_config_h.html.

That is probably the best way to achieve it, just copy the latest m4 file for that macro in your project and let it be found by `autoreconf`. You can refer to my write-up in [Autotools Mythbuster](https://autotools.io/autoconf/macros.html) for further details on using external macro files.